# Not typing sudo password everytime in terminal and apps like vscode

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Ubuntu, i'm running the 20.04 version. I'm using vscode and bash for creating some Symfony apps. The thing is that every time i try to save my work i have to type the sudo password and everytime i use the terminal for creating some symfony objects I also have to type my password. I heard that it's not recommended to run some apps as root, are there any other solutions for not having to type sudo password everytime I do something ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you're needing to use `sudo` to save work; there is something very wrong (*in my opinion*) with your approach & you should be evaluating that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know what you mean by "there is something very wrong" ? I mean, when i use CTRL + S to save my current work on visual studio code, Ubuntu ask me for sudo password. Thanks for reaching me!

Comment: You mention "*every time i try to save my work i have to type the sudo password*" which should **NOT** happen, ie. you're trying to solve an issue that is a result of something incorrect (*in my opinion*) with your existing approach/procedures.  You're seeking a solution to an existing behavioral issue, where you should be correcting the behavioral issue. It could also be I'm misunderstanding something with "*Symfony apps*" but your question reads as you seeking fixes to the wrong problem.